# Django why is this code blocking http requests

Tags: python, django

Here is the module:

```
import threading
import time
import pandas as pd

from binance.client import Client
import json

from api_create_alert.models import Alerts
from service_get_data.get_api_secret import get_secret

alerts = Alerts.objects.all().values()
df = pd.DataFrame(alerts)

data = get_secret()
data = json.loads(data)
client = Client(data['BINANCE_PUBLIC_API'], data['BINANCE_SECRET_API'])



def price_watch():
    interval = 10

    while True:
        coins = client.get_all_tickers()

        for coin in coins:
            symbol = coin['symbol']
            price = float(coin['price'])
            rows = df[((df.symbol == symbol) & (df.direction == 'ABOVE') & (price > df.price)) | ((df.symbol == symbol) & (df.direction == 'BELOW') & (price < df.price))]

            if len(rows) > 0:
                print(rows)

        time.sleep(interval)


thread = threading.Thread(target=price_watch)
thread.start()
```

Importing it from `apps.py`:

```
def ready(self):
    if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") == "true":
        import service_price_watch.price_watch
```

So it's a loop that runs every 10 seconds, each time the loop starts running the Django app is blocked no response is received until the loop is done, now why is that happening when I'm using the `threading` module, isn't the purpose of `threading` module is to make Async operations?

Comment: "until the loop is done" -- the loop doesn't have a `break`, so it never ends anyway?

Comment: If your django server isn´t a `uvicorn` or `daphne` and so on and your views aren´t set up as `async` your django server will always run `sync`operations. Is you app set up as an ASGI application?

Comment: @KlimBim this is not view, I not calling it thru API, the thread will start with the project, and I'm using `threading` shouldn't it create a new thread that runs async with the main django thread?